# What does canonical mean when used in sentence?

Tags: american-english, slang, translation

I just heard someone said "a canonical horrible idea"

I have been googling and still unable to understand exactly what "canonical" means when not used in programming language.

Can someone explain me what "canonical" actually means?

Comment: What was the context of that sentence?  What was the horrible idea, or why was it horrible?  This sounds to me like either a mistake, or new slang.

Comment: They were discussing about a startup idea (dog-salon recommendations) and then one of the members said that.

Comment: So then, like I said, this is either a misuse of *canonical* (doubly so, because they should have used the adverb *canonically*) to mean *definitely a horrible idea*, or else a new, slang meaning for the word. It's a mistake until other people start saying it too - then it's slang.

Comment: I can sort of guess what they meant, but the words make no sense.

Comment: Maybe they meant caninical (as in related to canines) ha!

Comment: Canonical has developed a use in hacker (computer programmer) culture to mean something like "the expected or standard way of doing things". So, although the quoted usage is a little unusual, I guess they meant that it was a classic exemplar of a bad idea. (Using "canonical" as a flat adverb, rather than "canonically".)

Comment: To misquote Gilbert & Sullivan ... "the very model of a horrible idea".

Answer (score 2):

**canonical**
adjective Also ca·non·ic.
1 pertaining  to,  established  by, or  conforming  to a canon or canons.
2 included  in  the  canon of  the   Bible.
3 authorized;   recognized;   accepted; canonical   works.
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/canonical

In short - authoritative
So, "a canonical horrible idea" would be an authoritatively horrible idea.

At least, that feels like the intent

Answer (score 1):

As in  such a bad idea that it is one of  several bad ideas which have come up so often that they are popularized as well known bad ideas.

Comment: It would help if you explained how you came up with that interpretation.

Comment: Definition 3 above.  It may also help if you look up the noun canon in a good dictionary.  If it is a canonical bad idea, it belongs to the canon of bad ideas, as the Book of Mark belongs to the canon of the Bible, and Empire Strikes Back  belongs.to the canon of Star Wars.